# "fileloop-next-file: Read error: Is a directory" when running project-query-replace-regexp

Tags: debugging, project

Hitting this error when trying to run `project-query-replace-regexp`. The project I'm working under has git submodules, if that could cause any issues? (Redacted some of the directories and search strings)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Read error" "Is a directory" "/Users/x/x/x/common/x")
  insert-file-contents("/Users/x/x/x/common/x" nil)
  fileloop-next-file(t)
  fileloop-continue()
  project-query-replace-regexp("x::x::x::x" "y::y::y::y")
  funcall-interactively(project-query-replace-regexp "x::x::x::x" "y::y::y::y")
  call-interactively(project-query-replace-regexp nil nil)
  command-execute(project-query-replace-regexp)
```

Running: `GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95)) of 2022-04-04`

`project.el`: Version: 0.8.1

Config (using straight)

```
(use-package project
  :bind-keymap ("C-x p" . project-prefix-map))
```

Comment: The debugger seems to be telling you that the next "file" in the loop is a directory, and function `insert-file-contents` can't handle a directory as its argument. If you feel this wasn't from your doing then maybe consider reporting it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Sure thing, filed a bug. I guess it was from doing since I invoked the command :). But joking aside, no, I have not altered anything or done anything out of the ordinary. Guessing that there's some interaction with this directory structure I have.

Comment: For posterity, that's http://debbugs.gnu.org/55382.